# jQuery- Detect change in the content of a SPAN field

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have the below piece of code which is used to simulate a text box:

```
<label for="alertCmpVal">ALERT VALUE:</label>
<span class="center textBox displayField highlight" id="alertCmpVal" contenteditable> <?php print $alert_val;?> </span>
```

I need to know when the content changes, e.g. I click on it, and change it from 0 to 1.

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(document.body).on('change','#alertCmpVal',function()
    {   
        alert("boo");
        $('#alertCmpVal').removeClass('highlight');
    })
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

(n.b. `$(document.body`) is used because on my main page, the initial field is loaded dynamically)

I'm guessing it is the 'change' that it doesn't like, but can't see what to replace it with. (jQuery / HTML5 is fine, as it is only used internally).

I've seen a few examples, but they generally seem to be for more complex scenarios, requiring multiple functions to detect the change when certain other things occur, but I figure there must be a simpler solution similar to the `on change` method.

Answer (score 41):

You can use this event `DOMSubtreeModified`:

```
$("span").on('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
  alert("Span HTML is now " + $(this).html());
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    $("span").html("Hello, World!");
  });
  $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "span", function () {
    alert("Span HTML is now " + $(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Hello</span>
<a href="#">Click</a>
```

Comment: This is very close, but it triggers when the dom is modified for the element AT ALL, not just for the html. This means any custom styles, attributes, data elements, or the like will also trigger this.

Comment: I think this event is also deprecated in DOM level 3 specification. Mozilla documents mutation events as a successor, but I'm unsure if those are widely accepted.

Comment: @CodeForGood I am not that good with Magento, but let me check.

Comment: @CodeForGood Just had a look at it. No idea mate. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, but the issue I am facing is purely connected with Jquery

Comment: @CodeForGood Yes, checked it. But it's something related to Klarna...

Comment: Ohhh, let me have a deep look again... @CodeForGood

Comment: Thanks a lot Praveen. You will be doing a great favor if you can correct my code. I only need to capture the content within a specific span tag when its content changes?

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, I shall try adjusting your code to suit my needs and let you know in case I succeed.

Comment: Hmm, looking at mutation events, it seems they are unreliable and actually obsolete. I would stray away from them (or manage when YOU change the dom by making a special DOM modifying class). 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

It's compatibility has decent browser coverage too (down to ie11 it seems). 

Could be iffy on ie9 or 10 if you need those though (but try your best to not, as those browsers were a huge pain)

Answer (score -7):

i think this code will help you.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myId').bind( "contentchange", function(){
        alert("Changed");
    });

    $( "#btn" ).click( function () {
        $('#myId').html( "Value" ).trigger( "contentchange" );
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RKLmA/192/

Comment: This is not detecting a change of content in a span which is what the question is.