# how to insert data from table columns of the given row only?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have a data table which looks like this
[image]

My table so far is

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>District</th>
            <th>VDC/MUNICIPAL</th>
            <th>Ward No.</th>
            <th>Camp Visited?</th>
            <th>Consense</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="persons : ${part}">
            <form method="post" th:action="@{/addReport}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" value="th:text='${ persons.name}'">
                <td contenteditable='true' th:text="${persons.name}"></td>
                <td contenteditable='true' th:text="${persons.lastName}"></td>
                <td contenteditable='true' th:text="${persons.age}"></td>
                <td contenteditable='true' th:text="${persons.sex}"> </td>
                <td contenteditable='true' th:text="${persons.district}"></td>
                <td contenteditable='true' th:text="${persons.vdcMun}"></td>
                <td contenteditable='true' th:text="${persons.wardNo}"></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input type='hidden' value='no' name='attendStatus'>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="yes" name="attendStatus">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-control">
                        <input type="hidden" name="file" value="null">
                        <input id="file" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </td>
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${persons.id}" name="id">
            </form>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have used `thymeleaf` to iterate data throughout the columns and it is working fine. this table successfully saves the data but now I want to add edit feature. all the table columns are editable so whenever I click on one column I can edit it. the edited data should now be saved into my database. (I don't need help to save data i.e back-end). I want to pass value of edit column(td) if it is edited else pass just pass the value as it is.

How can I do so? any javascript code or ideas will be welcome.

Comment: did you try add some id? and save/update the row in your database

Comment: some lead: [onchange for table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960759/onchange-event-of-table-td)

Answer (score 0):

In that case we used to have a hidden param as i see u have too . U just need to remember the value of unique Id that is auto generated in DB. Just map those values to each row , Use it as an identifier , When Editing happens U can send the Id back with the edited data so that you can identify which row to edit based on Id. Pardon me if misunderstood your questions.